# Why is $f(z)y^k$ bounded for $f$ a cusp form?

Tags: complex-analysis, number-theory, analytic-number-theory, modular-forms

For $f$ is a cusp form of weight $2k, k>0$  ($f(z)=(cz+d)^{-2k}f(\frac{az+b}{cz+d}$)), then why is $f(z)y^k$ bounded?

If expanded $f$ in $\sum a_nq^n$, it's domain is a open disc, hence I can't use compactness to  conclude, help please.

Comment: I'm not sure, but... won't $q\to 0$ exponentially as $y\to\infty$, so the series $\sum_{n>0}a_nq^n$ does the same. Therefore $f(z)z^n$ is bounded in a neigborhood of the cusp $i\infty$. Using the form condition allows you to transport this argument to a neighborhood of any cusp. Taking into account  periodicity you are left with the complement of such neighborhoods in a strip - i.e. a compact set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It suffice to prove it on the fundamental domain, and for $y$ large, $|y^kq(y)|\leq 1$, hence $f(z)y^k$ is bounded for $|y|\geq N$, and its complement in fundamental domain is compact, hence is bounded.